# ASP.net MVC - Razor HTML Helper is grabbing memory and not letting go

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have a brand new ASP.Net MVC project that is eating up memory and refusing to release it, for reasons I'm unable to fathom.

**The Application**

The site has just 2 pages, both served by the HomeController.

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GC.Collect();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        GC.Collect();

        var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            homeViewModel.MyList.Add(new MyClass
            {
                Field1 = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                Field2 = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
                Field3 = "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
                Field4 = "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
                Field5 = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
                Field6 = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
            });
        }

        return View(homeViewModel);
    }
}

public class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<MyClass>();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
    public string Field6 { get; set; }
}
```

You'll notice that both the Index and List actions force a garbage collection at the beginning of each call.

The Index page simply contains the shared _Layout.cshtml and no other content.

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

The List page contains a table of 300 rows, each row showing 6 string properties of a class designed to demonstrate my issue.

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Page";
}

<table class="table table-condensed">
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field1</td>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field2</td>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field3</td>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field4</td>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field5</td>
            <td style="@MyHelpers.DetermineStrikethruStyle(true)">@item.Field6</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

As you can see, the cells in the table are styled based on the result from a Razor HTML Helper, as follows:

```
@helper DetermineStrikethruStyle(bool isStrikeThru)
{
    @(isStrikeThru ? "text-decoration: line-through;" : "")
}
```

**The Problem**

Below you can see how the memory is being eaten up each time the List page is refreshed.

*On launch – Display Home Page*

[image]

*After Refreshing Index Page x 10*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 1st Time*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 2nd Time*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 3rd Time*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 4th Time*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 5th Time*

[image]

**Avoiding the Problem**

By simply removing the calls to the Razor HTML Helper within the List page avoids the issue entirely.

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Page";
}

<table class="table table-condensed">
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Field1</td>
            <td>@item.Field2</td>
            <td>@item.Field3</td>
            <td>@item.Field4</td>
            <td>@item.Field5</td>
            <td>@item.Field6</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

*On launch – Display Home Page*

[image]

*After Refreshing Index Page x 10*

[image]

*After Displaying List Page for the 1st Time*

[image]

*… after 5th time*

[image]

*… after 25th time*

[image]

*… after 50th time*

[image]

**Any ideas?**
I'm stumped at the moment, and have an unusable application as a result.

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: Assuming you've posted the code as-is, without trying to simplify it, there's not really anything here that would cause a memory leak. It's possible that there's something in how your defining the Razor helper that's causing more memory to be consumed than should be. What if you try adding this helper as an `HtmlHelper` extension, rather than using the `@helper` syntax?

Comment: I would love to see why helper declared using directive caused the issue in any of new answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
@helper DetermineStrikethruStyle(bool isStrikeThru)
{
    @(isStrikeThru ? "text-decoration: line-through;" : "")
}
```

on a HtmlHelper Extensions method in server side.

```
public static string DetermineStrikethruStyle(this HtmlHelper helper, bool isStrikeThru)
{
    return isStrikeThru ? "text-decoration: line-through;" : String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This has done the trick. No more memory leak!  Thank you! But any idea why using Razor rather than HtmlHelper Extension method would cause this?

Comment: I don't know, but probably HtmlHelper is compiled inside an assembly and razer helper on a View is compiled on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is being recursive when you do `return View(homeViewModel);`

Try return View() for a default view and see if problem still stay.